# Replace letter after specified character (including specified character) (all instances) java String

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace every "§" and the character after it with nothing.

Example:

"§a§b Text"

Goes to:

" Text"

§a turns to nothing because there is the character §. Same with §b.

How would I go about doing this?

I know about String.replaceAll(), but since the second character can be anything, I'm not sure how I would get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dot for the "any character" part:

```
str = str.replaceAll("§.", "");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Seriously made my day.